# How to set keys in a multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have doubt in php i want to set an associative array for which i have the keys ,as well as values.
 i have an array $headers and a mutidimentional array $data as follows:

```
$headers=(
    [0] => Testcase Name
    [1] => Cell Name
    [2] => Customer
    [3] => Flops
    [4] => Title
    [5] => Status
    [6] => Mfix CCR(open/close)
    [7] => Scenerio-Brief Description
    [8] => Expected Results
    [9] => CCR Status
    [10] => CCR No.
    [11] => Remarks
    [12] => Testcase Path
)

$data=(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /a/b/c
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
            [3] =>
            [4] =>
            [5] => Done
            [6] => close
            [7] => 2D Elastic with scanformat=parallel
            [8] => No miscompares for both scan and logic tests
            [9] =>
            [10] => 1716280
            [11] =>
            [12] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /x/y/z
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
            [3] =>
            [4] =>
            [5] => Done
            [6] => close
            [7] => 2D Elastic with scanformat=parallel & explicitshifts
            [8] => No miscompares for both scan and logic tests
            [9] =>
            [10] => 1717028
            [11] =>
            [12] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => /a/p/q
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
            [3] =>
            [4] =>
            [5] => Done
            [6] =>
            [7] => Error if explicitshifts greater than scan length
            [8] => No miscompares for both scan and logic tests
            [9] =>
            [10] =>
            [11] =>
            [12] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => /s/m/p
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
            [3] =>
            [4] =>
            [5] => Done
            [6] =>
            [7] => 2D Elastic + wide 1 Masking with scanformat=parallel
            [8] => No miscompares for both scan and logic tests
            [9] =>
            [10] =>
            [11] =>
            [12] =>
        )

)
```

I want to set the numeric keys [0]....[12] as the values of $headers array.
Means i want to replace [0]....[12] with $header[0]....$headers[12].

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $temp = array(); 
    foreach($val as $k => $v){
       $temp[$header[$k]] = $v; 
    }
    $result[] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$dataWithKeys = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $dataWithKeys[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, array_combine is cleaner way to achieve this. Thumbs up :)

Comment: `array_combine` frustrates me, it's picky that the arrays are the same size.  Just saying.

Comment: Arrays in the question are the same size too. If the size is different, then this is a completely different task.